# Stanford classifiers vs Weka classifiers

Tags: java, nlp, classification, weka, stanford-nlp

What is the significant advantage/difference between weka and stanford nlp classifiers ? And when /which use case either of them are recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answers the best:

> But for small data sets and numeric predictors, you'd generally be better off using another tool such as R, Weka or scikit-learn. Where the Stanford Classifier shines is in working with mainly textual data, where it has powerful and flexible means of generating features from character strings. However, if you've also got a few numeric variables, you can throw them in at the same time.

(quote from Stanford classifier page)